# Hive: group by calculated column

Tags: sql, group-by, hive

I need to execute query like

```
select 
myUsualField, SOME_FUNCTION(myAnotherField) as myUnusualField 
from MYTABLE
group by 
myUsualField, myUnusualField
```

In Hive this query fails: it cannot find field myUnusualField among other fields of the table.

Does this mean that in order to group by any calculated column in Hive I have to use subqueries?

```
select * from (
    select 
    myUsualField, SOME_FUNCTION(myAnotherField) as myUnusualField 
    from MYTABLE
) sourceTable
    group by 
    myUsualField, myUnusualField
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try repeating the expression:

```
select myUsualField, SOME_FUNCTION(myAnotherField) as myUnusualField 
from MYTABLE
group by myUsualField, SOME_FUNCTION(myAnotherField) ;
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But if I have several calculated columns, and some of them have very long and complex expressions (like case when) - it will make my query quite ugly..

Comment: @MiamiBeach . . . Then use a subquery or CTE.